# Laravel - How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I am having some issue while I need to remove and use only one time Country Name. Here is my Controller,

```
public function countryname($country_name){
$country_name = Request::segment(2);

// Dtabase Query to get all Country List
$data = DB::table('country')->where('country_name', '=', $country_name)->get(); // Simple Array Returns

// Return View with Data from DB
return view('country')->with('data', $data);
}
```

and In View Blade, for Country, I am trying to print Single Country for All Owners and then repeat Owner Name,

Country Name Section,

```
@foreach ($data as $row) 
 {!! $array = array_unique($array); !!}
 {{ $row->country_name }}
@endforeach
```

and then printing all owner's as;

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
   @foreach ($data as $row) 
      {{ $row->owner_name }}
   @endforeach
</div>
```

can someone please help to make it done? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I would sort them by country and then do an `if` statement inside a loop to create a new header for the new country if it's changed and list the names if not.